# Ng bootstrap modal don't open

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I've had this problem since this morning and I can't solve it, I've tried a lot of things but there's no way I can get it opened.

In practice I have to implement a test button that opens a modal with a header and a body, in addition there must be a closing and a disengagement button. This part of `HTML` works and I tested it, the problem is the part of `TypeScript`.

In the open function there is the command `const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);` that doesn't work correctly, the fact is that the command works, in fact if instead of `NgbdModalContent` I put a string works, so it's just `NgbdModalContent` that should theoretically take HTML.

If you have any idea how to do this would be of immense pleasure, below I leave you the files concerned.

PS. are new to this world, especially about `Angular2` and `TypeScript` so criticism and comments are welcome (I know I've made a big mistake and probably a trivial one (for you)). THANK YOU SO MUCH

TypeScript

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'post-ngb-modal-demo',
  templateUrl: './modal-demo.component.html',

})
export class NgbModalDemoComponent{
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
  }
}


export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

HTML

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add dynamically created components to entryComponents inside your @NgModule in your app.module.ts.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ....
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        NgbdModalContent,
        ...
    ],
    entryComponents: [NgbdModalContent],
    providers: [
        ....
    ]
})
```